# What is meant by the phrase "driving process" in stochastic processes?

Tags: stochastic-processes, terminology, definition

I have heard the phrase a lot when someone refers to a stochastic process as being "driven by a Brownian motion" or the "levy process that drives it" etc.

In this context, what is meant by "driving process"?

I assume it means something like if a process $X(t)$ can be defined using the SDE

$$dX_t = a(t,X_t) dt + B(t) dW_t$$

Then it is driven by the process $W_t$? But I'm not sure of the exact definition.

Comment: In all contexts I've seen that's what it means. I don't know if there's a formal definition.

Comment: Sweet as, thanks. I wasn't really expecting a formal definition, just wanted to make sure I wasn't mistaking it for something else. Thanks for the prompt answer!